# React native, Drawer navigation icon is cut

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

So far so good, I'm in the learning stage and hope some one can help me a little.

I'm working with react native and I'm trying to add icons to drawer navigation but one of the icons/paper-plane is cut,

[image]
Can some one show me how do I make the space around the icon bigger.?

````
import {createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';
import Notifications from '../screens/Notifications';
import SendNotifications from '../screens/SendNotifications';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const headerNavigationOptions = {
    header: props => <Header {...props} />
};
const routes = {
    Home: {
        screen: AppNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Home',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon name="home" size={25} color={tintColor}  /> )
        }
    },
    Notifications: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Notifications: {
                screen: Notifications,
                navigationOptions: headerNavigationOptions
            }
        }),
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Notifications',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon name="bell" size={25} color={tintColor}  /> )
        }
    },
    SendNotifications: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            SendNotifications: {
                screen: SendNotifications,
                navigationOptions: headerNavigationOptions
            }
        }),
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Send Notifications',
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Icon name="paper-plane" size={25} color={tintColor}  /> )
        }
    }
};
const routeConfig = {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    drawerBackgroundColor : '#013a65',
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#ffffff',
        activeBackgroundColor : 'transparent',
        inactiveTintColor : '#ffffff',
        },
        iconStyle: {
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
        },
};
export default createDrawerNavigator({
    ...routes
}, routeConfig);```
````

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with increasing the width and height in **routeConfig > contentOptions > iconStyle** or decreasing the size in 
`<Icon name="paper-plane" size={25} color={tintColor} />` ?

Comment: Please post your query as a comment instead of answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I had no sufficient reputation to comment. That's why I post like this. Sorry about it.